# Export model with texture files included to external site

Tags: texturing, export

Ok so there's a website I have to use for school to view 3D models that I have made. When I put my model in without the textures it says that it isn't missing any files, but when I use a model I downloaded without the textures, it says it's missing files. How do I fix that? Also this isn't just limited to the website, my model just won't let me add textures to it in any other program.[image]

As you can see in the top left here, it says missing files and then the name of the texture
[image]

And here, it doesn't say that there's any missing files.

Sorry I'm really new to blender and I would really appreciate a bit of help because I just spent 3 hours trying to figure out how to export the texture and I would literally cry myself to sleep knowing all that had gone to waste.

Also the website is 3dviewer.net

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you are doing actually with blender?

Comment: 3dviewer.net says it only supports 3ds, obj, stl and off. Which one/s are you using and what are the settings in the export (screenshots please)?

Comment: found a discussion here about that site and mtl files and how to view errors in the browser console https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/help-with-3d-viewer-babylon/1275

Comment: I managed to upload a model with working texture by doing the following : -create a BLENDER INTERNAL material with a texture ; -export it in .obj (with default settings) ; -drag and drop these 3 files into the viewer : .obj, .mtl and texture (.png in my case). I hope it helps.

Comment: @rob it's an obj file, and my settings are default

Comment: @Sazerac I'm making a 3d model for my school project and I just made a texture for it, and we have to present it so I found a website to view 3d models, but when I upload the .obj, the .mtl, and the texture (png), the whole thing is gray.

Comment: @thibsert I did that, but my texture just doesn't show up

Comment: nevermind, I figured out another strategy.